# AzureAD joined computer cannot authenticate to ADDS joined storage account (Kerberos coexistence)

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, azure-files

Overview:

I have two Azure storage accounts with Azure Files.

\\storagez.file.core.windows.net\share1 (Identity based access set to Microsoft Entra Kerberos)
\\storagex.file.core.windows.net\share2 (Identity based access set to AD DS)

I have successfully setup Microsoft Entra kerberos authentication for my hybrid identity XYZ\Username that is syncing from ADDS to AzureAD.

I followed this instruction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-hybrid-identities-enable?tabs=azure-portal#prerequisites

Problem:

I want to map a network drive to \\storagex.file.core.windows.net\share2

This portion of the article talks about mapping the AD DS realm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-hybrid-identities-enable?tabs=azure-portal#configure-coexistence-with-storage-accounts-using-on-premises-ad-ds

I mapped the realm using ksetup /addhosttorealmmap storagex.file.core.windows.net XYZ

I rebooted and confirmed this was added to the registry on my client machine.

I have tried using both my hybrid account AzureAD credential and my XYZ\username AD DS account.

I receive System error 86 has occurred.  The specified network password is not correct.

The AzureAD group that provides permission to storageX and storageZ includes my username identity.

What could I be missing to configure coexistence so that my AzureAD joined computer an authenticate to my StorageX storage account?

Comment: Is Kerberos authentication enabled on the storage account?

Comment: Yes Kerberos works on the storageZ account.  I can login to a remote workstation using AzureAD and map a drive to StorageZ without any credentials as I am receiving Kerberos passthrough as designed.

It is not supported to enable Kerberos on an account that is setup for ADDS.  That is the reason for one storage account with ADDS and one with Kerberos.

My quandary here is about the host to realm mapping that there is sparse coexistence documentation around.

Comment: As far as I understand now you want use AD DS with Azure Files. Have you seen this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-ad-ds-enable. There is also the `Debug-AzStorageAccountAuth` powershell cmdlet which might help in troubleshooting. And there is also this https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-files-samples/tree/master/AzFileDiagnostics/Windows